# Submenu with bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am not so expert in CSS and Bootstrap so I can not build 2 submenus.
Do you have a simple solution for me?

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">SAI</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Titolo <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sottotitolo 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sottotitolo 2</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sottotitolo 3 <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Nuovo sottotitolo 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nuovo sottotitolo 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nuovo sottotitolo 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nuovo sottotitolo 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nuovo sottotitolo 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

I have found some solutions on this site but they are too complex for me because I also have a few problems with the English language.

Thanks

Giampiero

Comment: You might want to: -get a friend to translate. - double-check Stack OverFlow's rules on what to ask and how to ask it, so you can help us help you. For starters, include what you have tried, what happens, and what you'd like to happen. As is, you are asking us to do work for you, and it's not the right place for that.

Comment: It appears you know Italian. I do too. If you'd like to tag me after finding some in Italian (and adding it *after* your English question), you can.

Comment: Also, there is SO in a few languages. See if any of them are easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small example for you that implements a Bootstrap dropdown with a small custom addition to support a sub-menu that opens on hover:

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Sub-menu <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS (compiled from LESS)**

```
li.sub-menu {
  position: relative;
}
li.sub-menu span.glyphicon {
  font-size: 0.7em;
}
li.sub-menu:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

You can see this working example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amvavW

You should read the documentation on how to create dropdown-menus with Bootstrap:http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

They have practical explanations that comes bundled with some code and working examples.

**As much as I remember(correct me if I am wrong)**: Bootstrap currently does not natively support N-levels dropdown menus, so what you do is kind of use their built-in dropdown implementation and add a bit of custom CSS to get more sub-menu levels working in the way that you desire.

Hope it helps a bit!